# why is Parameterless constructor not being found?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm trying to return a pagedList to my Post action..

My class...

```
   public class TrackerModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string EquipmentID { get; set; }
    public string EquipmentDescription { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime? ExpectedReturnedToCustomer { get; set; }
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime? DateOfCalibration { get; set; }
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime? NextDueDate { get; set; }

    public bool StatusChange { get; set; } //01/07/2014

    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }

    public PagedList<TrackerModel> pagedList { get; set; }

    public TrackerModel() { }

}
```

Reference in my View.
(Note this is a partial view used within the Index view and I'm using the Post Index action for the form submission, so the model gets past to the Post Index action )

```
    @model IPagedList<TrackerModel>
```

The return on my Get action...

```
  var customerViewList = Mapper.Map<IList<Calibration>, IList<TrackerModel>>(calibrationList);

        IPagedList<TrackerModel> pagedList = customerViewList.ToPagedList(filter.Page, filter.PageSize, totalRecords);

        return PartialView("AllCalibrations", pagedList);
```

and my Post action so far...

```
   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(IPrincipal user, PagedList<TrackerModel> model)
```

Error encountered..

"No parameterless constructor defined for this object"
I thought, public PagedList pagedList { get; set; }
or public TrackerModel() { } , would take care of this, but unfortunately not.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does `PagedList<>` have a parameterless constructor?

Comment: public PagedList<TrackerModel> pagedList { get; set; } in the Tracker Class , doesn't that cover it ??

Comment: Could the error be referring to the controller? Where does the exception come from when you debug it?